# How to prove the invertibility of some elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have numbers $\overline{55}, \overline{65}, \overline{75} \in \mathbb{Z}_{231}$ and I am wondering how to prove that one of these numbers is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_{231}$.

Comment: $\;75\;$ isn't....

Comment: Sorry i mean 231 not 321

Comment: My comment remains....and edit your question.

Comment: 75 still isn't.  75 isn't invertable for 123,213,132,231,312,or 321.  Not invertable for any of those.

Comment: And 55 is invertible for 123 but not 132.  Is invertable for 213 but not 231.  Is invertible for 312 and 321.

Comment: google euclids algorithm or euclids lemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a theorem... that answers this.

But I will let you find it on your own.

Play with...

$55 = 11*5; 231 = 11*3*7$

$55a \equiv 1 \mod 231$ means $55a = 1 + 231k$

$5*11*a - 3*7*11*k = 1$

$11(5a - 21k) = 1$

Is that possible?

$65 = 5*13; 231 = 3*7*11$

So $65*a \equiv 1 \mod 231$ means $65a = 1 + 231k$ so $5*13*a - 3*7*11*k = 1$.

Is that possible?

Play with

$65 \equiv 65 \mod 231$

$65*4 = 260 \equiv 29 \mod 231$

$29 \equiv 29 \mod 231$

$29*8 = 232 \equiv 1 \mod 231$

So $1\equiv 29*8 \equiv (65*4)*8 = 65*32 \mod 231$

So $65^{inverse} \equiv 32 \mod 231$ and indeed $65*32 =2080=9*231 + 1$.

So what do you think about $75$?

Notice we could *not* have done the above with $55$.

$55 \equiv 55 \mod 231$

$55*4 = 220 \equiv -11 \mod 231$

$-11*-23 = 231 \equiv 0 \mod 231$

So that method doesn't get us anywhere.

Comment: Caution ! 231 = 11 * 7 * 3 = 11 * 21, not 11 * 23.

Comment: Gore blimey!  You are right!

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Look at the gcd of those numbers with 321.